# PostgeSQL - How to put some fields of multiple rows with same id in pre defined rows on single line

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is really messed up so I'll do my best to explain my mind...

I'm building one big SQL query on a Postgres database. In this query, i need to put 10 "sets" of 3 pre defined columns in the result.

What I mean is that I need to create fields like this :

[image]

Repeated until **F10**

In every query, I always need to return these 10 sets of fields.

Then, what I need to put in these fields come from another select subquery.

```
SELECT 
"REL_DATE_REALISATION" AS "Date finale",
"REL_RETARD" AS "Retard",
CASE
WHEN "REL_PENALITY" = true
THEN 'OUI'
ELSE 'NON'
END AS "Excusé"
FROM "REL_LIVRABLE"
LEFT JOIN "L_LIVRABLE" ON "REL_LIV_ID"="LIV_ID"
WHERE "REL_OFF_ID"=10583
```

This query uses the same ID as the parent query, and can return at most 10 rows

Here's an example : 
[image]

What I need to do now, is to display every rows returned by the subquery in the sets of columns I'm creating.

In my example above, the first line will fit in the three first F1 columns, the second line in the 3 first F2 columns and so on.

Hope my explanations are clear...

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: So in the end you are sure that your subquery always returns exactly 10 records?

Comment: No, what I say is that i need to always return 10 sets of 3 columns in my final query, but the subquery can return at most 10 rows, but it's the maximum, it can return 1, 2, 3 ... In that case, the other sets will stay empty

Comment: There's no order to the F1, F2, etc?  In your example F2 is before F1.

Comment: Not clear enough for my limited mind. Could you put some dataset that you have in the first place and the exact result that you need?